# Gradle no descarga librerias de cucumber

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

Estoy tratando de crear un proyecto para probar la herramienta **Cucumber** (ATDD) y valorar si es posible utilizarla para otro proyecto. Los requisitos que se me presentan es que sea capaz de trabajar con Java, JUnit, Gradle e IntelliJ (este ultimo a nivel de integración de plugins).

El problema es que, al parecer, gradle no es capaz de descargar las dependencias necesarias para trabajar con este framework (estas mismas dependencias si que se descargan con maven). El fichero `build.gradle` es el siguiente:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    //testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.2.4'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.2.4'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-html:0.2.3'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4'
    testCompile 'info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.5'
}
```

Si ejecuto el comando `gradle dependencies` obtengo la siguiente traza:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- junit:junit:4.11
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.2.4 FAILED
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-html:0.2.3 FAILED
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4 FAILED
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4 FAILED
\--- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.5 FAILED

testRuntime - Runtime classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- junit:junit:4.11
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-core:1.2.4 FAILED
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-html:0.2.3 FAILED
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.4 FAILED
+--- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:1.2.4 FAILED
\--- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.5 FAILED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.484 secs
15:54:20: External task execution finished 'dependencies'.
```

De hecho, IntelliJ muestra las dependencias del siguiente modo:

[image: IntelliJ]

¿A qué puede deberse este problema?

Comment: Puedes forzar la descarga delibrerias por comando ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies